# Nested JSON for categories/subcategories and fetching unique elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am creating JSON for sports and sub sports which looks like this:

```
{
    "sportName": "Men's Basketball",
    "path": "mbasket",
    "sportID": 7,
    "parentSportName": "Basketball"
}, {
    "sportName": "Women's BasketBall",
    "path": "wcc",
    "sportID": 8,
    "parentSportName": "Basketball"
}, {
    "sportName": "Women's Cross Country",
    "path": "wbasket",
    "sportID": 9,
    "parentSportName": "Cross Country"
}, {
    "sportName": "Men's Cross Country",
    "path": "mcc",
    "sportID": 10,
    "parentSportName": "Cross Country"
}
```

Now I want to **nest sportName under parentSportName**, i.e.
Cross Country will contain Men's Cross country and Women's Cross Country. What changes I need to do in my JSON?

PS:I am creating a **nested list**.

Comment: Are you seeking suggestions on how your JSON should look or asking how the transformation can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an top-level array of parent sports which contains a nested sports array.  This example passes the json lint validator.

```
var parentSports= 
    [
      {
         "parentSportName": "Basketball",
         "sports":[
           {
             "sportName": "Men's Basketball",
             "path": "mbasket",
             "sportID": 7
           }, {
             "sportName": "Women's BasketBall",
             "path": "wcc",
             "sportID": 8
           }]
      },{
         "parentSportName": "Cross Country",
         "sports": [
            {
             "sportName": "Women's Cross Country",
             "path": "wbasket",
             "sportID": 9
            }, {
             "sportName": "Men's Cross Country",
             "path": "mcc",
             "sportID": 10
            }]
      }
    ];
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jrf37/